# ember.js discard created model if not saving

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have followed the 3 parts of the tutorial [here](http://mentalized.net/journal/2014/06/10/ember_on_rails_03/) and everything is working fine, with one exception. When I go to the "Add the book" page and then navigate to "List books" without saving, the list of books is extended by an empty item. I suspect that the reason is the following code, where the new model is created before saving and not removed if not saving the form. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
Embertest.BooksNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.get('store').createRecord('book');
  },
  actions: {
    create: function() {
      var newBook = this.get('currentModel');
      newBook.save();
      this.transitionTo('books');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_deactivate

Add a `deactivate` function on your route. This is called before exiting this current route. So you can roll back the record you just created in the model like this:

```
model: function(params) {
    return this.get('store').createRecord('book');
},

deactivate: function() {
    this.currentModel.rollback();
},
```

Comment: This does not work for me - deactivate does not get invoked if I am navigating away from the page.

Comment: Are you sure you placed it in the route?

Comment: Yes. I guess it is not working because I am sort of staying within the same route when navigating away due to nested resources (i.e. /posts/new -> /posts).

Comment: then you can just add the code above in the /posts/new.js route. This works for me on my part.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by attaching an action to destroy the record to the willTransition event as below. Would anyone comment if this is the right approach?

```
Embertest.BooksNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.get('store').createRecord('book');
  },
  actions: {
    willTransition: function() {
      if (this.currentModel.get('isNew')) {
          this.get('currentModel').deleteRecord();
      };  
    },
    create: function() {
      var newBook = this.get('currentModel');
      newBook.save();
      this.transitionTo('books');
    }
  }
});
```